# How to handle administrator-controlled accounts on iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, icloud, keychain

I am building an iOS app that is going to be used internally within my company. An administrator wants to be able to give certain employees logins to use the app across multiple devices.

For example, Administrator will assign Employee A and Employee B their own username and password. The app will be installed on Device X, Y, and Z. Employees A and B need to be able to login to any device (say, Device X), do stuff in the app and save their changes, and then login to another device (say, Device Z) and see their changes. Administrator would like to be able to manage the logins within the app (i.e. after entering an administrator password).

I have looked into iCloud Keychain to store the username/password pairs but it sounds like Keychain is meant to only be used with one Apple ID (which I assume all company devices would be attached to one Apple ID so maybe Keychain could work).

In summary, my questions are:

1. Where can I securely store user login information (if not on Keychain)? Do I need my own server or are there  services within the Apple API that would help accomplish this?
2. How can I utilize the logins from any device with my app?
3. Are there any APIs or Wrappers that would simplify this process? I found [Locksmith](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith) but I'm not sure if it will work for what I need.

I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: You are going to need some sort of server backend that the app talks to.  The app would just be a client.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a back-end server. However, if you are looking for a simpler solution, I would recommend AWS Mobile Hub:

https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/

They provide Authentication and NoSQL services without having to setup your own servers. All in all, it's a pretty comprehensive offering.